# Student schengen visa refusal

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, study

Last November 2017 my schengen student visa (French) was rejected. The reason stated was "the consular authority did not find/have sufficient/ reliable content".

Now I've been trying for Australia for my higher education and have completed all the pre requisites for my course, but I have not yet received an acceptance from any university I have applied to.

What is the reason behind this? Does the visa refusal have this much of a concern?

Comment: How would the universities even know about the refusal? Have you mentioned it to them?

Comment: As NidhiK said, it is unlikely to affect the universities in Australia. But it could affect the Aus visa office either by data sharing or because there is a real problem with your visa application. You should review that refusal: the reason you quoted doesn't make much grammatical sense.

Comment: We can't know why the university has made whatever decision they've made -- if they've even decided yet. In any case, there's nothing you can do about it, now. You'll just have to wait and see.

Answer (score 4):

> Now I've been trying for Australia for my higher education and have
>   completed all the pre requisites for my course, but I have not yet
>   received an acceptance from any university I have applied to.
>
> What is the reason behind this? Does the visa refusal have this much
>   of a concern?

Visa refusals have no bearing on university admissions. In fact you may be admitted to a university, and still be denied a student visa.

The two are not connected whatsoever.